# How to boot from existing LUKS partition? (dual boot)

Tags: boot, system, kernel, encryption, refind

I installed elementary os on my laptop that already has some OS's installed. The way I achieve this is;

- I have an efi partition `/dev/sda1`
- I have a LUKS container in `/dev/sda2`
- The LUKS container has a LVM volume group names `Linux`
- I have a logical volume named Elementary under the LVM, accessible at `/dev/mapper/Linux-Elementary`

I already have a boot loader (rEFInd) configured, so what I did when I installed elementary is;

- Booted live USB
- Used terminal to launch the installer with `--no-boot` parameter; since I already have a boot loader.
- Used `cryptsetup open` to decrypt the LUKS container at `/dev/sda2`
- Installed EOS on `/dev/mapper/Linux-Elementary`
- Copied all files in `/boot` to my ESP and edited fstab accordingly.

However, this leaves me with a couple hiccups. I suspect the initrd does not have any decryption built into it, because if I supply the kernel parameter `cryptdevice=UUID=<UUID-here>:cryptroot` no decrpytion happens, and after a while I am dumped to busybox initramfs. There is a function in busybox called `cryptroot unlock` but it gives me an output `sed: /conf/conf.d/cryptroot: No such file or directory` when I run it. I am unfamiliar with ubuntu based methods of doing this; how do I add decryption to initramfs? (I can chroot in from my other distros to run commands)

I also see a lot of files under `/boot`, (`config-*`, `abi-*`, `retpoline-*`, `System.map-*`) which leads me to think that regular kernel parameters might not be enough. (I use `rw quiet splash root=/dev/Linux/Elementary` in addition to the cryptdevice parameter) Can anyone guide me on what kernel parameters I should use? (Or share your working `refind_linux.conf`?)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I just read this article today, I think its not relevant anymore, but if you or someone else still has the same problem try the following steps.
Ensure that you have put "dm-crypt" in your /etc/modules file of your elementary OS installation.
You should also put GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="kopt=root=/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root" into the /etc/default/grub configuration file of your elementary installation if you are using grub as a boot loader and do an update-grub with chroot.